# EPPlus Excel Exporting hides some tabs

Tags: c#, excel, export, epplus

I am using C# with EPPlus library.
The task is that I am opening an excel file, removing some sheets from it and saving it as a separate excel file.

The issue I am facing is that the excel sheet tabs at the bottom are moved out of view in the output file saved:

[image]

The activesheet is sheet 1, but the Sheet 1 tab is not visible on the excel file.

Is there any command using EPPlus which can amend this to look like:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look like an EPPlus issue, but Excel sheet area. Try resizing the Excel horizontal scrollbar, that usually happens when there is little space for the sheets. Also, note that you can use the arrows on the left to go throught the sheets.

Comment: @Magnetron : The saved file needs to open showing the Sheet1 tab automatically. Also, there is actually enough space on the horizontal area to accommodate all the tabs. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Please, post a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Files saved by Excel can contain information about the width of the tab area. I am quite sure that EPPlus does not take care of this detail.

If you rename a `.xlsx` file to `.zip` and take the `xl\workbook.xml` file of it you will find a section  that may contain an attribute 'tabRatio'. The attribute is present only if the width is adjusted manually. This attribute or the whole section may be deleted.

[image: Screenshot of XML]

I did a test: I saved a file with too little space for the tabs and after deletion of the section the tab area looked fine again.

Maybe EPPlus generates the 'tabRatio' attribute but with useless values? Please check for it. If so, you might want to file a request for the developers to leave it out if it does not make sense.